# Android 'has no access to content://...' when using Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT

Tags: android, android-fileprovider

This is a question about permission of Android file system. If there could be more base/extended knowledge, I would be very grateful.

- When using default app(file selector/default file explorer/gallery), the program runs OK.
- When using Quickpic(a gallery software) to choose image, the program still runs normally.
- But when using ES File Explorer, code crushes with `SecurityException`

[image]

The log showes both above return uri `selectFile: content://media/external/images/media/212736`, why the latter failed. **How/Can I write a program which can support all third part file selector app?**(without asking for file permission. You know, using default file explorer to pick file doesn't need permission of READING)

Here's some my hello world code

```kotlin
mPickResultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(
    ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()
) { result ->
    if (result.resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        val data = result.data
        val uri = data?.data
        Log.d(TAG, "selectFile: $uri")

        // open file
        contentResolver.openInputStream(uri!!)?.use {
            val bytes = it.readBytes()
            Log.d(TAG, "selectFile: ${bytes.size}")
        }
    }
}
```

```kotlin
private fun selectFile() {
    val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT)
    mPickResultLauncher.launch(intent)
}
```

My test phone is Redmi K30, MIUI 14(Android 12).

Comment: `takePersistableUriPermission` was never meant to be used with `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` - it only works for `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`. Is there a reason why you aren't using that if you want persistent access to the returned Uri?

Comment: Dont understand why you talk about default file selecter (whatever that would be) or Qiick Pick or ES File Explorer. The only thing that is relevant is that you use ACTION_GET_CONTENT. You can treat all obtained content schemes the same.

Comment: @blackapps Sorry for not explaining the problem clearly. I added an image to show how these third part apps open. The question is that, although the uris are same, the uri supplied by ES File Explorer is not accessible.

Comment: @ianhanniballake Sry for adding an unnecessary line, I have deleted it from question. The purpose is to read file from an uri given by third part app.

Comment: Are you telling that ES File Explorer gives you an uri like content://media/external/images/media/212736 ? Hard to believe.

Comment: @blackapps Yes. The more interesting thing is, both Quickpic and ES File Exp return the same uri. If I use to select an image first, then use ES File Exp, the error doesn't occur. Seems that my app has the file access already. (before exit or re-launch)